# Rails 3 Joins -- Select only certain columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Below is a relationship between Comments and a user. Each comment has one user so I'm building out a join in the code below.

I was wondering how to build this code to only include specific columns in the join. I don't need all of the user information. Just the first_name. Any suggestions.

Current Code:

```
@comments = Comment.where(:study_id => @study.id).joins(:user)
```

Comment: Does your Comment model not have a :user association?  Are you trying to eager load user information?  What are you trying to accomplish with a join that ActiveRecord doesn't already give you?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to eager load the information. Currently, it does a user for the user for each comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
@comments = Comment.joins(:user)
                   .select("comments.*, users.first_name")
                   .where(study_id: @study.id)
```

Comment: Here joins would behave like inner join. Use includes otherwise:
User.includes(:comments).select(...)

Answer (score 5):

Extending Aldo's answer to show a way to retrieve the resulting foreign column value.

```
@comments = \
  Comment\
  .joins(:user)
  .select("comments.*, users.first_name as users_first_name")
  .where(study_id: @study.id)

# Now it's stored on each comment as an attribute, e.g.:
puts @comments.first.read_attribute(:users_first_name)
puts @comments.first.attributes['users_first_name']

# Note that inspecting the comment won't show the foreign data
puts @comments.first.inspect # you won't see user's first name output
```

You could also declare `users_first_name` as an attrib on the comment with attr_accessible. I don't think there's any magic way to automatically set it, but you could easily do so yourself in a post-select loop.

Comment: This works.  But beware - when you do inspect on the output (instance '@comments.first.inspect' or '@comments.inspect'), you will not see the joined data, and may be misled into thinking it is failing to pull it.  But when you specify the "as" name, specified, as in this example with the "puts" - it is shows up.