# Rails join, need both tables in result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables users (id, name ...) and user_group_users (user_id, usergroup_id)

I try to get a join on both tables, need something like this in result

user.id user.name user_group_users.user_id, user_group_users.user_group_id

Tried This:

```
@users = current_client.users.joins('LEFT INNER JOIN user_group_users ON user_group_users.user_id = users.id')
```

But in the result the user_group_users.user_id, user_group_users.user_group_id are missing

how can I solve that?

Models:

```
class UserGroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_group
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_users
  has_many :users, :through => :user_group_users
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :user_group_users, :through => :user_group_users
end
```

I want to generate this list, with all users: 
[image]

And I need the user_id and usergroup_id from usergroupusers to set the switcher on if the user is already in this group.

Comment: `LEFT INNER JOIN`? What is that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships for ActiveRecord objects? It looks like you're using rails to generate the join manually, but if all you want is the relation to be established to access the fields, then use the tools to your advantage. See Rails [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). If you really do need to do this explicitly for some reason, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322164/rails-3-joins-select-only-certain-columns) for an approach.

Comment: I've added some code above how we have set up the models. we use has many and belongs to

are there a better way to get the data we need?

Comment: Your `User` table doesn't lool right.  I think you want the "through" on the other attribute.

Comment: And add some of the attributes that are not about the relations, and an example of what attributes you are not able to find.

Comment: @Felix did you read the information in the link I provided for "Active Record Associations"? It describes in detail how these relations work.

Comment: Yes but, can't find a solution for my problem. added some more infos above

Comment: You are on the right track, you just need to fix your association, as I mentioned above.  Then you should be able to simply do stuff like `user.user_groups` and `user_group.users`.  Rails will take care of the join for you behind the scenes.

Comment: I read the active record associations, but can't find what you mean can you please give me a hint

Comment: Your `User` model:  The "through" clause is on the wrong attribute.  It should be on `user_groups`.

Comment: I changed that, but nothing changed. Do I have to change something on this line as well: `@users = current_client.users.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group_users ON user_group_users.user_id = users.id')`

Comment: You should not need to do any SQL.  Let rails do it.  If your schema is correct, it should just work.  You should be able to get the user_groups for any user, and the users for any user_group.

Comment: And how do I have to make the sql

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do too much and not letting Rails do the work it's intended to do for you. You should read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in Rails carefully, because all of the information you need is there, and you can find several examples online using Google.

In your case, you really only need a "has and belongs to many" relation. As described in the documentation, this is similar to the "has many... through" but doesn't require that your code know about the intermediate model (what you call, `UserGroupUser`).

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_groups
end
```

In your code, let's suppose you have a `UserGroup` active record object in `@group` and you have a user active record object in `@user`. Then this will tell you if the user is in the group:

```
@group.users.map { |u| u.id }.include? @user.id
```

If you want to check every user, then loop with `User.all.each do |user| ...`.

You can get rid of the `UserGroupUser` model, but you still need the table, as described in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I can't follow you at all. When I delete the model UserGroupUser, how can I save? I do it this way at the moment: `@user_group_user = UserGroupUser.new
      @user_group_user.user_id = params[:user_id]
      @user_group_user.user_groups_id =  params[:usergroup_id]` and where should I do the check if a user is in group in controller or in the view? when I do it the controller how should I combine the normal @user with the result of the check?

Comment: @Felix Rails will save the intermediary table information for you automatically when you save a User or a UserGroup. Again, I am assuming that you don't really need the data from the intermediary table since what you are really looking for is the User or UserGroup information.

Comment: can you show me how it should like if I save a user to a group? don't understand how it should work without that model

Comment: @Felix, save a user: `@user.save`. Save a group: `@group.save`. Rails does the rest. The link I gave for Rails Associations explains how to set the values of associations (such as `@user.user_groups....` or `@group.users...`

Comment: I try it ... but It dosn't work ... I tried this way: `@all = @user.user_groups` do you probably have about 2 miniutes in skype or so to explain it to me?

Comment: okay I'm one step closer to goal ... there was a spelling mistake