# Rails Eager Load Identifiers in has_many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Say I have the following models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I'm building an endpoint that retrieves all items, where each item should be coupled with the array of category IDs it belongs to. An example result would be:

```
[
    {
        name: 'My Item',
        category_ids: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    // more items...
]
```

With this configuration, I'm able to call `item.category_ids` on each record which results in the SQL that I want, which looks like `SELECT categories.id FROM categories INNER JOIN categories_items ... WHERE categories_items.item_id = $1`.

However, that obviously results in an N+1 - and I can't seem to find a way to do this now in an eager load. What I'm looking to do is get a list of items, and *just* the ID of the categories that they're in, by eager loading the `category_ids` field of each `Item` (although, if there's another way to accomplish the same using eager loading I'm okay with that as well)

*Edit to explain difference from the duplicate:*

I'm looking to see if it's possible to do two this in two separate queries. One that fetches items, and one that fetches category IDs. The items table is relatively wide, I'd prefer not to multiply the number of rows returned by the number of categories each item has - if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 Joins -- Select only certain columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322164/rails-3-joins-select-only-certain-columns)

Comment: `Item.joins(::categories).select("items.*, categories.id")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this seems like it works, but is not quite the solution I was hoping for. This approach forces it into a single JOIN query, as opposed to one query to fetch items and a separate (single) query against the M2M join table for the category IDs. It's not the end of the world, but it'll result in more data coming back. (I edited the question to clarify the difference I'm looking to achieve)

Comment: If you want two queries you can simply do `item = Item.find(1); item.categories.ids`

Comment: Right, but I'm doing this in a list. That approach will result in an N+1. Clarifying the question further :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a join model instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` will allow you to query the join table directly instead (without hacking out a query yourself):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_categories
  has_many :items, through: :item_categories
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :item_categories
end

class ItemCategory
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Note that the table naming scheme for `has_many through:` is different - instead of `items_categories` its `item_categories`. This is so that the constant lookup will work correctly (otherwise rails looks for `Items::Category` as the join model!) - so you will need a migration to rename the table.

---

```
items = Item.all
category_ids = ItemCategory.where(item_id: items.ids).pluck(:category_id)
```

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` is only really useful for the most simple M2M relations - as soon as you need to do anything slightly complex or might want to store metadata in the join table use `has_many through:` instead.

Comment: Perfect. Now I just need to figure out the best way to handle this in active model serializers. (I have a custom adapter for my API that includes IDs by default, and automatically expands to the full entities when requested). Thanks for your numerous answers!